# AngularJS custom provider causing "Unknown provider" exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a custom provider in AngularJS, which is supposed to be an application global configuration. Unfortunately, I am not able to inject this provider, because AngularJS throws "Unknown provider" exception. I have totally no idea what is wrong with my code.

### app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [
        'config'
    ])
    .config(configuration);

    configuration.$inject = ['ConfigProvider'];

    function configuration(ConfigProvider) {
        ConfigProvider.setFoo(86400);
    }
})();
```

### config-provider.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('config')
        .provider('ConfigProvider', ConfigProvider);

    ConfigProvider.$inject = [];

    function ConfigProvider() {
        var config = [];

        var provider = {
            $get: $get,
            setFoo: setFoo,
        };

        return provider;

        function $get() {
            return {
                getConfig: function () {
                    return config;
                }
            };
        }

        function setFoo(foo) {
            config['foo'] = foo;
        }
    }
})();
```

*config-provider.js* is loaded first in my scripts file, but changing the order does not change the behavior anyway - still "Unknown provider". Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should declare the provider without 'Provider' suffix:

```
module.provider('Config', ConfigProvider);
```

Comment: You are my savior! It's worth to mention for the others, that when you inject **Config** provider to the *config* method, it should be followed by "Provider" suffix - `configuration.$inject = ['ConfigProvider'];`. But when injecting to service, *Provider* suffix is obsolete - `FooService.$inject = ['Config']`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you change `ConfigProvider` to `config`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('config')
        .provider('config', config);

    config.$inject = [];

    function config() {
        var config = [];

        var provider = {
            $get: $get,
            setFoo: setFoo,
        };

        return provider;

        function $get() {
            return {
                getConfig: function () {
                    return config;
                }
            };
        }

        function setFoo(foo) {
            config['foo'] = foo;
        }
    }
})();
```

And then use it like below in u r app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [
        'config'
    ])
    .config(configuration);

    configuration.$inject = ['configProvider'];

    function configuration(configProvider) {
        configProvider.setFoo(86400);
    }
})();
```

Please `carefully` look at the `namings`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an empty array when you declare your `config` module : see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

```
angular.module('config', [])
```

Comment: That code is in the `config-provider.js`. I would guess that the `config module` is already declared in a seperate file, based on his naming conventions.

Comment: I have the *config* module declared in another file, as @BobbyW mentioned.